# Logic, the negation of the Earth is Round?

Tags: logic

The negation of the statement: the Earth is round is that the Earth is not round. Could we consider the statement that the Earth is Cube is the negation of the Earth is round?

Answer (score 4):

No. The assertion that the Earth is not round does not exclude the possibly that it might be rectangular, or even triangular, for example.

Comment: what about the statement all rabbits are black which is the negation of some rabbits are white? is it true?

Comment: The negation of "all rabbits are black" is "there exists some rabbit that is not black" and vice versa. In other words, to disprove the statement "all rabbits are black" it would suffice to procure a rabbit that is any color other than black, like brown or white. Just be careful: "not black" doesn't necessarily just mean "white," just as "not round" doesn't necessarily mean "cubed."

Answer (score 2):

No. The negation of "Earth is Round" could imply a Donut Shaped Earth. Thus you cannot infer from "It is not the case that Earth is Round" that "Earth is Cube". But from "Earth is Cube" you can infer "It is not the case that Earth is Round".

Comment: Too many ambiguous terms and in strict sense "Round" needs to be defined properly.

Answer (score 1):

We can explain this using sets.

Consider the infinite set of natural numbers:

Let $N = \{ 1, 2, \dots\}$

If we say $x \in N$ and $x \ne 2$, it does not automatically mean $x = 3$. It means $x \in \{1, 3, 4, 5, \dots \}$.

The reason why we need to talk about $x \in N$ is to sharply bound the statement. In your example the statement is *Earth is round*. If we take the set of all statements about the Earth, one could presumably say *Earth is a solar planet*. Saying $x \in N$ is equivalent to clarifying that we are talking about the ***shape*** of the earth and not the type of ***celestial body*** that Earth is.